# If $f(x)=x-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0f(x)\sin(x)dx$ find the explicit function for $f(x)$ in its simplest form

Tags: integration, functions

> A function $f(x)$, where $x$ is a real number , is defined implicitly by the following formula:
>   $$f(x)=x-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0f(x)\sin(x)dx$$
>   Find the explicit function for $f(x)$ in its simplest form.

This question appeared in the recent New Zealand Qualifications Authority 2016 Scholarship Calculus examination.

---

What I have done

Let $f(x)=y$

$$f(x)=x-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0f(x)\sin(x)dx \Rightarrow y=x-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0y\sin(x)dx$$

$$ y=x-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0y\sin(x)dx  \Leftrightarrow \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0y\sin(x)dx=x-y$$

Consider the integral

$$ \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0y\sin(x)dx$$

Let $u=y\Rightarrow du=dy$ and $dv= \sin(x) \Rightarrow v=-\cos(x)$

$$ \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0y\sin(x)dx = \left[y\sin(x) \right]^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0+\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\cos(x) dydx$$

How can I continue?

Comment: The use of $x$ in the integral and outside of the integral is somewhat hard to read.

Comment: @SimpleArt This is how the question was worded  , sorry.

Comment: @Joseph , haha how did you know it was from the NCEA exam?

Comment: @dydxx I just sat it! :) I came looking for some pointers, and this question was the first one I saw.

Comment: @Joseph I found it extremely hard compared to last years paper, conics killed me haha.

Comment: I don't think we're supposed to post exam questions?  :/

Comment: @SimpleArt hi the exam finished and this question is posted after the exam so doesn't effect anything ;$

Comment: Ah, ok, just checking ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**.  The integral in your equation is a **definite** integral and evaluates to a constant.  Therefore
$$f(x)=x-c$$
where $c$ is a constant satisfying
$$c=\int_0^{\pi/2} (x-c)\sin x\,dx\ .$$
Evaluate the integral, then solve the equation to find $c$.

Answer:

> $c=\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=x-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0f(x')\sin(x')dx'$$
multiply by $\sin(x)$ and integrate from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$:
$$f(x)\sin(x)=x\sin(x)-\left(\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0f(x)\sin(x)dx\right)\sin(x)$$
$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0f(x)\sin(x)dx=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0x\sin(x)dx-\left(\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0f(x)\sin(x)dx\right)\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\sin(x)dx$$
$$x-f(x)=1-(x-f(x))(1)$$
So
$$2(x-f(x))=1$$
which means
$$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Be careful. You should not use $x$ as both the variable of integration and a variable outside the integral. They are different things and should be named differently.

Comment: Agreed, but the first equation was from the question...